# Cancel response in case of canceled request for django

Tags: python, angularjs, django, request, response

Let's assume, we have some king of autosuggest on client and as user type we continiously sent requests to our backend. Each character user type, sent new request.
To optimize this, we can have some delay before sending new request, but this does not cover every case. The backend code to respond to this is rather complex, we would like to cancel already sent requests. This is possible in JS code, but the backend still made his job with only difference, that response is not consumed.

Question: what possible solutions to get backend notified, that we no more need his response and we can interrupt our handler.

We work with Django, gunicorn, nginx and AngularJS, but more general solutions are also interesting.

Comment: Just check when the user inputs something? (I.e keypress or similar)

Comment: @Sayse yes, we already do so. This cover client part, but we need to interupt backend code. Actually, we need to asume, that we made our client code in a best way and there no more to improve.

Comment: There isn't any feasible way (that I know of) to really interupt the backend since requests are asyncronous and it would get even more convoluted to figure out who made what request and in what order.

Comment: @Sayse possible - yes. But gunicorn are able interupt his workers on timeout, so probably there is way to interupt on connection close. The hard things is that there is nginx behind it... So I'm not sure, there is solution, but would like to hear, what community can suggest.